Axe Core Puppeteer Opening White browser with node JS
When I am trying to implement puppeteer plugin in node js blank browser is opening, I don't want to open that white window when we are making headless as true.
Below is the code how I am implementing the puppeteer
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    args: [
       '--no-sandbox', '--disabled-setuid-sandbox'
    ]
})

